# RSocket retrieveFlux() with Kotlin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, reactive-programming

I am trying to write a client for my server (both in Kotlin and using Spring Reactive Web). I encountered this problem while trying to use the RSocket. How can I get a Flux using RSocket?
[image: code]

```
@Component
class RSocketClient(val rSocketRequester: RSocketRequester) {
    data class Header(val playerToken: Int)

    fun matchmake(): Flux<Int> {
        return rSocketRequester.route("matchmaking")
                .data(Header(0))
                .retrieveFlux(Int)
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Int.javaclass` ?

Comment: @zlaval Type mismatch.
Required:
Int!
Found:
Int.Companion

Comment: If you requiered java Integer class, use `Int::class.javaObjectType ` if KClass is needed, then just use `Int::class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get reference of `Class`. You can use either `Int::class.java` or `Int::class` depending whether you need java `Class` or `KClass` reference

```
@Component
class RSocketClient(val rSocketRequester: RSocketRequester) {
    data class Header(val playerToken: Int)

    fun matchmake(): Flux<Int> {
        return rSocketRequester.route("matchmaking")
                .data(Header(0))
                .retrieveFlux(Int::class.java)
    }
}
```